# Find object in array of object by checking its array of objects if the array contain a object with given criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of objects of products' categories like this:

```js
[{
    id: 1,
    name: "A",
    products: [{
      id: 1,
      price: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "B",
    products: [{
      id: 2,
      price: 1
    }]
  }
]
```

please help me with a function that using product's id to return the category name. I've tried but my result always return "A" regardless of which product ID I've input, even the nonexistent one.
This is what I tried so far:

```js
const populate = function(productID) {

  // main code here
  return categories.find(x => {
    let products = x.product;
    console.log(products.find(e => e.id = productID));
    if (products.find(e => e.id = productID) != undefined) return true;
    return false;
  }).name;
}
```

I've looked for anywhere but there are not any answer for my problem.

Comment: It's a typo. You wrote `=` when you meant `==` in the `find()` calls.

Comment: Oh right! Silly me. I've fixed it and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is just a silly typo.
I fixed it by changing

```js
if (products.find(e => e.id = productID) != undefined) return true;
```

to

```js
if (products.find(e => e.id == productID) != undefined) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Get the `products`
(you can use destructuring) and loop over to get the product whose `id` is equal to `productID`.

**2)** There may be a chance you couldn't find the product then you you should handle that case as well. For that, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

You can also make it one-liner as

```
const populate = (productID) => categories.find(({ products }) => products.find(({ id }) => id === productID))?.name;
```

```js
const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "A",
    products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        price: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "B",
    products: [
      {
        id: 2,
        price: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const populate = function (productID) {
  return categories.find(({ products }) => {
    return products.find(({ id }) => id === productID);
  })?.name;
};

console.log(populate(2));
```

Comment: What does the question mark mean at the end of find()?

Comment: that is not just `?` it is `?.` [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)